# Verifying Powerball® lottery odds to win. Why am I getting different odds than the official website advertises?

Tags: rust

I know a little bit of Rust and I've decided to buy a Powerball ticket today just for fun. While checking the odds of winning, I figured why not see if I can verify them in Rust as a fun exercise. Well, this is where things got interesting. The thing is, the math seems to check. Or does it?

**Context:**
Select five numbers between 1 and 69 for the white balls, then select one number between 1 and 26 for the red Powerball.

[image: powerball_official_odds]

### Grand Prize - Match 5 + PB

This DOES calculate correctly.

```rust
// Match 5 + Powerball: 1 in 292,201,338
fn combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut result: u64 = 1u64;
    for i in 0..r {
        result = result * (n - i) / (i + 1);
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    let white_balls_combinations: u64 = combinations(69, 5);
    let powerball_combinations: u64 = combinations(26, 1); // This is essentially just 26, as C(26,1) = 26
    let total_combinations: u64 = white_balls_combinations * powerball_combinations;
    println!("Total combinations possible: {}", total_combinations);
}
```

[Rust Playground - Match 5 + Powerball](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%2F%2F+Match+5+%2B+Powerball%3A+1+in+292%2C201%2C338%0Afn+combinations%28n%3A+u64%2C+r%3A+u64%29+-%3E+u64+%7B%0A++++let+mut+result%3A+u64+%3D+1u64%3B%0A++++for+i+in+0..r+%7B%0A++++++++result+%3D+result+*+%28n+-+i%29+%2F+%28i+%2B+1%29%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++result%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+white_balls_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2869%2C+5%29%3B%0A++++let+powerball_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2826%2C+1%29%3B+%2F%2F+This+is+essentially+just+26%2C+as+C%2826%2C1%29+%3D+26%0A++++let+total_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+white_balls_combinations+*+powerball_combinations%3B%0A++++println%21%28%22Total+combinations+possible%3A+%7B%7D%22%2C+total_combinations%29%3B%0A%7D)

### Prize - Match 5

This appears to calculate correctly but DOES NOT match the official website.

```rust
// Match 5: 1 in 11,238,513
fn combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut result: u64 = 1u64;
    for i in 0..r {
        result = result * (n - i) / (i + 1);
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    let white_balls_combinations: u64 = combinations(69, 5);
    println!("Total combinations possible: {}", white_balls_combinations);
}
```

[Rust Playground - Match 5](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%2F%2F+Match+5%3A+1+in+11%2C238%2C513%0Afn+combinations%28n%3A+u64%2C+r%3A+u64%29+-%3E+u64+%7B%0A++++let+mut+result%3A+u64+%3D+1u64%3B%0A++++for+i+in+0..r+%7B%0A++++++++result+%3D+result+*+%28n+-+i%29+%2F+%28i+%2B+1%29%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++result%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+white_balls_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2869%2C+5%29%3B%0A++++println%21%28%22Total+combinations+possible%3A+%7B%7D%22%2C+white_balls_combinations%29%3B%0A%7D)

### Prize - Match 4 + PB

This appears to calculate correctly but DOES NOT match the official website.

```rust
// Match 4 + Powerball: 1 in 22,477,026
fn combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut result: u64 = 1u64;
    for i in 0..r {
        result = result * (n - i) / (i + 1);
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    let white_balls_combinations: u64 = combinations(69, 4);
    let powerball_combinations: u64 = combinations(26, 1); // This is essentially just 26, as C(26,1) = 26
    let total_combinations: u64 = white_balls_combinations * powerball_combinations;
    println!("Total combinations possible: {}", total_combinations);
}
```

[Rust Playground - Match 4 + Powerball](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%2F%2F+Match+4+%2B+Powerball%3A+1+in+22%2C477%2C026%0Afn+combinations%28n%3A+u64%2C+r%3A+u64%29+-%3E+u64+%7B%0A++++let+mut+result%3A+u64+%3D+1u64%3B%0A++++for+i+in+0..r+%7B%0A++++++++result+%3D+result+*+%28n+-+i%29+%2F+%28i+%2B+1%29%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++result%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+white_balls_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2869%2C+4%29%3B%0A++++let+powerball_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2826%2C+1%29%3B+%2F%2F+This+is+essentially+just+26%2C+as+C%2826%2C1%29+%3D+26%0A++++let+total_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+white_balls_combinations+*+powerball_combinations%3B%0A++++println%21%28%22Total+combinations+possible%3A+%7B%7D%22%2C+total_combinations%29%3B%0A%7D)

### Prize - Match 4

This appears to calculate correctly but DOES NOT match the official website.

```rust
// Match 4: 1 in 864,501
fn combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut result: u64 = 1u64;
    for i in 0..r {
        result = result * (n - i) / (i + 1);
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    let white_balls_combinations: u64 = combinations(69, 4);
    println!("Total combinations possible: {}", white_balls_combinations);
}
```

[Rust Playground - Match 4](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%2F%2F+Match+4%3A+1+in+864%2C501%0Afn+combinations%28n%3A+u64%2C+r%3A+u64%29+-%3E+u64+%7B%0A++++let+mut+result%3A+u64+%3D+1u64%3B%0A++++for+i+in+0..r+%7B%0A++++++++result+%3D+result+*+%28n+-+i%29+%2F+%28i+%2B+1%29%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++result%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+white_balls_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2869%2C+4%29%3B%0A++++println%21%28%22Total+combinations+possible%3A+%7B%7D%22%2C+white_balls_combinations%29%3B%0A%7D)

### Prize - Match 3 + PB

This appears to calculate correctly but DOES NOT match the official website.

```rust
// Match 3 + Powerball: 1 in 1,362,244
fn combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut result: u64 = 1u64;
    for i in 0..r {
        result = result * (n - i) / (i + 1);
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    let white_balls_combinations: u64 = combinations(69, 3);
    let powerball_combinations: u64 = combinations(26, 1); // This is essentially just 26, as C(26,1) = 26
    let total_combinations: u64 = white_balls_combinations * powerball_combinations;
    println!("Total combinations possible: {}", total_combinations);
}
```

[Rust Playground - Match 3 + Powerball](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%2F%2F+Match+3+%2B+Powerball%3A+1+in+1%2C362%2C244%0Afn+combinations%28n%3A+u64%2C+r%3A+u64%29+-%3E+u64+%7B%0A++++let+mut+result%3A+u64+%3D+1u64%3B%0A++++for+i+in+0..r+%7B%0A++++++++result+%3D+result+*+%28n+-+i%29+%2F+%28i+%2B+1%29%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++result%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+white_balls_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2869%2C+3%29%3B%0A++++let+powerball_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2826%2C+1%29%3B+%2F%2F+This+is+essentially+just+26%2C+as+C%2826%2C1%29+%3D+26%0A++++let+total_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+white_balls_combinations+*+powerball_combinations%3B%0A++++println%21%28%22Total+combinations+possible%3A+%7B%7D%22%2C+total_combinations%29%3B%0A%7D)

### Prize - Match 3

This appears to calculate correctly but DOES NOT match the official website.

```rust
// Match 3: 1 in 52,394
fn combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut result: u64 = 1u64;
    for i in 0..r {
        result = result * (n - i) / (i + 1);
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    let white_balls_combinations: u64 = combinations(69, 3);
    println!("Total combinations possible: {}", white_balls_combinations);
}
```

[Rust Playground - Match 3](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%2F%2F+Match+3%3A+1+in+52%2C394%0Afn+combinations%28n%3A+u64%2C+r%3A+u64%29+-%3E+u64+%7B%0A++++let+mut+result%3A+u64+%3D+1u64%3B%0A++++for+i+in+0..r+%7B%0A++++++++result+%3D+result+*+%28n+-+i%29+%2F+%28i+%2B+1%29%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++result%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+white_balls_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2869%2C+3%29%3B%0A++++println%21%28%22Total+combinations+possible%3A+%7B%7D%22%2C+white_balls_combinations%29%3B%0A%7D)

### Prize - Match 2 + PB

This appears to calculate correctly but DOES NOT match the official website.

```rust
// Match 2 + Powerball: 1 in 60,996
fn combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut result: u64 = 1u64;
    for i in 0..r {
        result = result * (n - i) / (i + 1);
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    let white_balls_combinations: u64 = combinations(69, 2);
    let powerball_combinations: u64 = combinations(26, 1); // This is essentially just 26, as C(26,1) = 26
    let total_combinations: u64 = white_balls_combinations * powerball_combinations;
    println!("Total combinations possible: {}", total_combinations);
}
```

[Rust Playground - Match 2 + Powerball](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%2F%2F+Match+2+%2B+Powerball%3A+1+in+60%2C996%0Afn+combinations%28n%3A+u64%2C+r%3A+u64%29+-%3E+u64+%7B%0A++++let+mut+result%3A+u64+%3D+1u64%3B%0A++++for+i+in+0..r+%7B%0A++++++++result+%3D+result+*+%28n+-+i%29+%2F+%28i+%2B+1%29%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++result%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+white_balls_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2869%2C+2%29%3B%0A++++let+powerball_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2826%2C+1%29%3B+%2F%2F+This+is+essentially+just+26%2C+as+C%2826%2C1%29+%3D+26%0A++++let+total_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+white_balls_combinations+*+powerball_combinations%3B%0A++++println%21%28%22Total+combinations+possible%3A+%7B%7D%22%2C+total_combinations%29%3B%0A%7D)

### Prize - Match 1 + PB

This appears to calculate correctly but DOES NOT match the official website.

```rust
// Match 1 + Powerball: 1 in 1,794
fn combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut result: u64 = 1u64;
    for i in 0..r {
        result = result * (n - i) / (i + 1);
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    let white_balls_combinations: u64 = combinations(69, 1);
    let powerball_combinations: u64 = combinations(26, 1); // This is essentially just 26, as C(26,1) = 26
    let total_combinations: u64 = white_balls_combinations * powerball_combinations;
    println!("Total combinations possible: {}", total_combinations);
}
```

[Rust Playground - Match 1 + Powerball](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%2F%2F+Match+1+%2B+Powerball%3A+1+in+1%2C794%0Afn+combinations%28n%3A+u64%2C+r%3A+u64%29+-%3E+u64+%7B%0A++++let+mut+result%3A+u64+%3D+1u64%3B%0A++++for+i+in+0..r+%7B%0A++++++++result+%3D+result+*+%28n+-+i%29+%2F+%28i+%2B+1%29%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++result%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+white_balls_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2869%2C+1%29%3B%0A++++let+powerball_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2826%2C+1%29%3B+%2F%2F+This+is+essentially+just+26%2C+as+C%2826%2C1%29+%3D+26%0A++++let+total_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+white_balls_combinations+*+powerball_combinations%3B%0A++++println%21%28%22Total+combinations+possible%3A+%7B%7D%22%2C+total_combinations%29%3B%0A%7D)

### Match Powerball

This appears to calculate correctly but DOES NOT match the official website.

```rust
// Match Powerball: 1 in 26
fn combinations(n: u64, r: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut result: u64 = 1u64;
    for i in 0..r {
        result = result * (n - i) / (i + 1);
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    let powerball_combinations: u64 = combinations(26, 1); // This is essentially just 26, as C(26,1) = 26
    let total_combinations: u64 = powerball_combinations;
    println!("Total combinations possible: {}", total_combinations);
}
```

[Rust Playground - Match Powerball](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%2F%2F+Match+Powerball%3A+1+in+26%0Afn+combinations%28n%3A+u64%2C+r%3A+u64%29+-%3E+u64+%7B%0A++++let+mut+result%3A+u64+%3D+1u64%3B%0A++++for+i+in+0..r+%7B%0A++++++++result+%3D+result+*+%28n+-+i%29+%2F+%28i+%2B+1%29%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++result%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+powerball_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+combinations%2826%2C+1%29%3B+%2F%2F+This+is+essentially+just+26%2C+as+C%2826%2C1%29+%3D+26%0A++++let+total_combinations%3A+u64+%3D+powerball_combinations%3B%0A++++println%21%28%22Total+combinations+possible%3A+%7B%7D%22%2C+total_combinations%29%3B%0A%7D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to account for having won a larger prize and exclude that possibility from the lower prizes.

For example, notice that the odds for just matching the Powerball number alone are 1 in 38.32. You're 1 in 26 to match the Powerball number, but 1 in 38.32 to do so **and** not match any of the five white balls.